# Android JSON Problems

Tags: php, android, json

I have been working on a java app which uses a remote mysql database to retrieve data. I have a webserivce inbetween the app and the database which outputs the data in JSON format.

I'm trying to parse the JSON file, not getting any errors but the screen on the APP is blank.

I have searched for hours for different methods to do this, I have sorted out all errors that I have come across but I don't know how to go from here.

MenuActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;



public class MenuActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    // The JSON REST Service
    static String URL = "http://alirajrestaurant.com/app/get.php";

    // Will hold the values I pull from the JSON
    static String itmName = "";
    static String itmDesc = "";
    static String itemPrice = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        //Add Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        //Setup Home Navigation Button
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //display UP Icon
        new MyAsyncTask().execute();





    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        //Navigate Right Button on Toolbar to get to next Activity
        if(id==R.id.navigate_right)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(this,ResActivity.class));
        }

        //What to do if Home Button is clicked
        if(id==android.R.id.home)
        {
            NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            // HTTP Client that supports streaming uploads and downloads
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());

            // Define that I want to use the POST method to grab data from
            // the provided URL
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);

            // Web service used is defined
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            // Used to read data from the URL
            InputStream inputStream = null;

            // Will hold the whole all the data gathered from the URL
            String result = null;

            try {

                // Get a response if any from the web service
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // The content from the requested URL along with headers, etc.
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                // Get the main content from the URL
                inputStream = entity.getContent();

                // JSON is UTF-8 by default
                // BufferedReader reads data from the InputStream until the Buffer is full
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);

                // Will store the data
                StringBuilder theStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;

                // Read in the data from the Buffer untilnothing is left
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {

                    // Add data from the buffer to the StringBuilder
                    theStringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                }

                // Store the complete data in result
                result = theStringBuilder.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {

                // Close the InputStream when you're done with it
                try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}
                catch(Exception e){}
            }

            // Holds Key Value pairs from a JSON source
            JSONObject jsonObject;
            try {


                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result.substring(3));


                // GET ARRAY DATA
                JSONArray jArray =  new JSONArray();

                JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(' ');
                // Pulling items from the array
                itmName = oneObject.getString("name");
                itmDesc =oneObject.getString("desc");
                itemPrice = oneObject.getString("price");




            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result){

            // Gain access so I can change the TextViews
            TextView line1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name_result);
            TextView line2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.desc_result);
            TextView line3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.price_result);

            // Change the values for all the TextViews
            line1.setText( itmName);

            line2.setText(itmDesc);

            line3.setText("£: " + itemPrice);

        }

    }



    }
```

JSONParse.java

```
public class JSONParse {

public JSONArray GetAllItems()
{
    // URL for getting all customers


    String url = "http://alirajrestaurant.com/app/get.php";

    // Get HttpResponse Object from url.
    // Get HttpEntity from Http Response Object

    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;

    try
    {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  // Default HttpClient
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();



    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        // Signals error in http protocol
        e.printStackTrace();

        //Log Errors Here



    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    // Convert HttpEntity into JSON Array
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

    if (httpEntity != null) {
        try {
            String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            Log.e("Entity Response  : ", entityResponse);

            jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return jsonArray;


}
```

}

PHP Script

```
<?php  

    $db_host = 'localhost';
    $db_name = 'abx';
    $db_user= 'abx';
    $user_pw = 'abx';

//PDO is a extension which  defines a lightweight, consistent interface for accessing databases in PHP.  
$dbn='mysql:host='.$db_host.'; dbname='.$db_name; 

    try {
        $db=new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.'; dbname='.$db_name,$db_user,$user_pw );
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        echo "this is displayed because an error was found";
        exit();
}


//here prepare the query for analyzing, prepared statements use less resources and thus run faster  
$row=$db->prepare('select itemName, itemDescription, itemPrice from tblMenu');  

$row->execute();//execute the query  
$json_data=array();//create the array  
foreach($row as $rec)//foreach loop  
{  
$json_array['name']=$rec['itemName'];   
    $json_array['desc']=$rec['itemDescription'];  
    $json_array['price']=$rec['itemPrice'];  
//here pushing the values in to an array  
    array_push($json_data,$json_array);  

}  

//built in PHP function to encode the data in to JSON format  
echo json_encode($json_data);  





?>
```

I'd be greatful if someone can help me out, this beginning to drive me insane now....

Answer (score 0):

Put this in `onCreate`:

```
// Gain access so I can change the TextViews
TextView line1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name_result);
TextView line2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.desc_result);
TextView line3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.price_result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP page does not return JSON format.

Here is what I see:

```
<html>
<head> 

    <title> Head </title>

</head>
<body>
[{"name":"Hash Tikka","desc":"Spicy barbecued duck","price":"4.15"},{"name":"Lamb or Chicken Tikka","desc":"Spicy pieces of barbecued Lamb or Chicken","price":"4.10"}]  
</body>
</html>
```

This is no  valid JSON format as this is JSON in HTML.

Get ridd off the HTML and check again your parsing.